# How to save the query result in a variable and use it in another query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to save the last generated voucher in a variable and used as an input for another query..

```
$last = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(voucherno) AS `last` FROM `purchasebill` ORDER BY no DESC LIMIT 1')->row_array();
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `purchaseitem`  where vno= '$last[0]' ORDER BY  vno " )->result_array();
```

I tried like the above code it gives me an error undefined offset 0..Help me to save the last generated voucher no in an last variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [document](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html), `$last[0]` will return entire first row. In your case you want to access the value of `MAX(voucherno)` which is stored in an alias `last`.

Change `$last[0]` to `$last['last']` in your next query and it shall work.

```
"SELECT * FROM `purchaseitem` WHERE vno = '{$last['last']}' ORDER BY vno"
```